# How to store R model coefficient for use in python-based production system?

Tags: python, r, serialization, machine-learning, dev-to-production

I have a situation where I need to train a model in R and then use the model coefficients obtained from that (betas) in order to perform a regression classification in semi-live data. This production system is implemented in pure python (data processing) and django (web interface).

The model coefficients will be calculated every week manually and right now produces a csv, that is read by the python code. I just wanted to know if there are any better ways of doing this?

This is mostly a question on what are the established best practices for cases like this, even though the current approach works.

Comment: I think this question could be salvaged but right now it's too much of a shopping-question and I'd tend to voting to close it.

Comment: I know that DMG has PMML http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/GeneralStructure.html but I never tried it and don't know what it's worth